# Adding the word "APPENDIX" to Table of Contents in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents

My appendix style looks like this:

```
\newboolean{@@inappendix}
\newcommand{\@@appendixname}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
  \setboolean{@@inappendix}{true}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
%  \coversheet{\uppercase\expandafter{\@@appendixname}}  % REMOVE COVERSHEET
  \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{\appendixname}%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%
```

Then in the main tex file I have:

```
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
```

In the appendix1 tex file I have:

```
\chapter{Flooding Test Graphs}
```

The actual appendix page title looks fine, but the TOC looks like this:

> A FLOODING TEST GRAPHS

I would like it to say:

> APPENDIX A FLOODING TEST GRAPHS

There are similar questions and answers posted, but I still can't seems to get it to work.

On the last line of the style file I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{APPENDIX\Alph{chapter}}
```

This just writes "APPENDIX" over "A FLOODING TEST GRAPHS"

Comment: the `\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par ... \Alph{chapter}}` seems to be missing a `}` in your example... is that in your code too?

Comment: This response helped, but it's not quite what I need yet.
I need the whole word Appendix to be capitalized in the Table of Contents. Right now, only the "A" is capitalized. Also, when I use the appendices environment, it puts the word APPENDIX followed by a number above the chapter heading for each chapter even if the chapter is not in the Appendix. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 33):

Use `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}` and then use the `appendices` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}% https://ctan.org/pkg/appendix
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{A chapter} \chapter{A chapter} \chapter{A chapter}

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{An appendix} \chapter{An appendix}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that adding `\usepackage{appendix}` isn't sufficient. You need to use the `titletoc` option (or specify `\appendixtocon`). Merely using `\appendix` also does not suffice; use the `appendices` environment.

Comment: This fails if you `\include{}` the appendix as a seperate file. using `\input{appendixfile}` fixes that issue.