Chapters are not displayed in the correct order
I have been trying to set up the chapter_3 as the same way as i set the chapter_2 but chapter_3 is not showing when i add at the end of the ordered chapters section in my main thesis.tex file. I have showed the order I have been trying to obtain at the end. Chapter_3 shows up when i change its position before chapter_2 but not showing at the end.
I have provided the order as below and my main thesis.tex file below.
\subfile{\main/tex/introduction.tex}


\subfile{\main/tex/chapter_2.tex}


\subfile{\main/tex/chapter_3.tex}


When i put chapter_3 before chapter_2 it shows up somehow. Below is the chapter_3.tex file content.
(chapter_3.tex file)
% A workaround to allow relative paths in included subfiles
% that are to be compiled separately
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153312/subfiles-inside-a-subfile-using-relative-paths
\providecommand{\main}{..}
\documentclass[\main/thesis.tex]{subfiles}

\onlyinsubfile{\zexternaldocument*{\main/tex/introduction}}
\usepackage{ mathtools, dblfloatfix}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{URDF} 

\section{Modelling a Robot with URDF}
Apart from the angle-set conventions mentioned above, there is also Z-Y-Z Euler angles convention  in many resources related to the Robotics. These convetions are examples of a set of 24 conventions that we will call angle-set conventions. Of these, 12 conventions are for fixed-angle sets, and 12 are for Euler-Angle sets. Note that, because of the duality of fixed-angle
sets with Euler-angle sets, there are really only 12 unique parameterizations of a
rotation matrix by using successive rotations about principal axes. There is often
no particular reason to favor one convention over another, but various authors
adopt different ones, so it is useful to list the equivalent rotation matrices for all 24
conventions. 
\end{document}

(main thesis.tex file)
% University of Alberta Example Thesis
% By the Rogue's Gallery, Department of Computing Science
% Last updated September 15, 2017

% Note: You will probably have to edit the uathesis.sty file
%       to comment or uncomment bits and pieces
%       (e.g. co-supervisor, externals, etc)

% A workaround to allow relative paths in included subfiles
% that are to be compiled separately
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153312/subfiles-inside-a-subfile-using-relative-paths
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}          % for default format
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package dependencies  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
% For cross-references between files
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77774/undefined-control-sequence-when-cross-referencing-with-xr-hyper
\usepackage{nameref,zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref} % See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization
\usepackage{tabulary} % Better text wrapping in tables. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
\usepackage{rotating} % For the 'sidewaystable' environment. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations
\usepackage{multirow} % For multirow/multicolumn cells in a table. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Columns_spanning_multiple_rows
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % A package that can be used to create sub-figures
\usepackage{enumitem} % for more control over enumerate
\usepackage{mdwlist}    % the 'note' environment
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Also used with biblatex
\usepackage{xmpincl} % Seems to be needed when converting to PDF/A, 
                     % particularly on Macs
\usepackage{listings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% biblatex    %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% (Added by Bernard Llanos)
% biblatex is intended to be the successor to BibTeX
% (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#biblatex)
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
style=ieee,%
backref=false,%
sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,%
mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2%
]{biblatex}
% `backref=true` adds back references - Links to the in-text citations from
% the corresponding bibliography entries. Back references are not mentioned
% in thesis guidelines, but are, in my opinion, helpful for reading and editing.

\usepackage[american]{babel}

% The following macro will put back references on the right edge of the page
% (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149009/biblatex-pagebackref-reference-in-the-flush-right-margin)
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
   \iflistundef{pageref}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addspace}%
      \printtext{\addperiod\hfill\rlap{\hskip15pt\colorbox{blue!5}{\scriptsize\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}}}

\addbibresource{\main/refs.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Glossary and acronyms (optional) %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}
\setglossarystyle{altlist}

% A simple, but limited way to produce a sorted glossary
% Other options are described in the 'glossaries' Beginner's Guide (https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)
\makenoidxglossaries % use TeX to sort

% Glossary entries will be loaded from a separate file
\loadglsentries{\main/tex/glossary}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Thesis style package %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{\main/uathesis}  % Earlier version says this should be last package 
                     % imported. Never checked if this is still true. 
                     % Having this second last before the next one seems fine.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Shorthands               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% From the CVPR paper template (http://cvpr2017.thecvf.com/submission/main_conference/author_guidelines)
% Add a period to the end of an abbreviation unless there's one
% already, then \xspace.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}

\def\eg{\emph{e.g}\onedot} \def\Eg{\emph{E.g}\onedot}
\def\ie{\emph{i.e}\onedot} \def\Ie{\emph{I.e}\onedot}
\def\cf{\emph{c.f}\onedot} \def\Cf{\emph{C.f}\onedot}
\def\etc{\emph{etc}\onedot} \def\vs{vs\onedot}
\def\wrt{w.r.t\onedot} \def\dof{d.o.f\onedot}
\def\etal{\emph{et al}\onedot}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title page and Table of Contents Tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% Correct title for TOC
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}





% Fill in the following
\title{Ros and Micro-Ros for Industrial Robotics Applications} % Title can't use formulae, symbols, superscripts, subscripts, greek letters, etc. all of which should be replaced with word substitutes
\author{Kaan Karaalioglu}






\degree{\MSc}
%\degree{\PhD} % uncomment respective degree



\dept{Computer Science}  % Write Computing Science or Civil Engineering.

% If you have a specialization, uncomment the following line and enter it below.
% It must correspond with what it says on Bear Tracks
% (Academics>My Academics>Graduation). If, like most people, you don't have one,
% just leave it commented.
%\field{Specialization Field}

% Put the year that you submitted your thesis below
\submissionyear{\number2024}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document Content  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% This is a modular document.
% The 'subfiles' package allows you to typeset the included
% documents separately from the main document, so that you
% can view only pieces of the thesis at a time.
% See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents
%
% Subfiles that contain references: You can just run
% `biber subfilename` on them when compiling them individually.
% There is no need to make them reference the bibliography database
% 'refs.bib', as they inherit the reference from this file.

\newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{}

\graphicspath{ {./"specific_images"/} }



\begin{document}
    

\renewcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{#1}

\preamblepagenumbering % lower case roman numerals for early pages

\titlepage % adds title page. Can be commented out before submission if convenient

\subfile{\main/tex/abstract.tex}

\doublespacing
% \truedoublespacing
% \singlespacing
% \onehalfspacing

% A preface is not always required
% \subfile{\main/tex/preface.tex}

% Below are the dedication page and the quote page. FGSR requirements are not
% clear on if you can have one of each or just one or the other. They do say to
% ask your supervisor if you should have them at all.
%
% The CS Department links to a comparison of pre- and post-Spring 2014 thesis
% guidelines https://www.ualberta.ca/computing-science/graduate-studies/current-students/dissertation-guidelines)
% The comparison document lists an optional dedication page, but no quote page.

\subfile{\main/tex/dedication.tex}
\subfile{\main/tex/quote.tex}

%\subfile{\main/tex/acknowledgements.tex}

\singlespacing % Flip to single spacing for table of contents settings
               % This has been accepted in the past and shouldn't be a problem
               % Now the table of contents etc.
               
\tableofcontents
\left 
\listoftables  % only if you have any
\listoffigures % only if you have any

% minimal support for list of plates and symbols (Optional)
%\begin{listofplates}
%...            % you are responsible for formatting this page.
%\end{listofplates}
%\begin{listofsymbols}
%...            % You are responsible for formatting this page
%\end{listofsymbols}
               
% A glossary of terms is also optional
\printnoidxglossaries
               
% The rest of the document has to be at least one-half-spaced.
% Double-spacing is most common, but uncomment whichever you want, or 
% single-spacing if you\left(  just want to do that for your personal purposes.
% Long-quoted passages and footnotes can be in single spacing
\doublespacing
% \truedoublespacing
% \singlespacing
% \onehalfspacing

\setforbodyoftext % settings for the body including roman numeral numbering starting at 1

%  ... The bulk of your magnificient thesis  goes here ... 
%  hopefully more than two lines! Use standard Latex sectioning commands
%  like \chapter etc. End with the bibliography
% See FGSR requirements for any additional requirements on the body

\subfile{\main/tex/introduction.tex}

\subfile{\main/tex/chapter_2.tex}

\subfile{\main/tex/chapter_3.tex}

\subfile{\main/tex/conclusion.tex}


% Renaming the bibliography: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
     %add the above line to get "References" in the table of contents.
%
\singlespacing % optional;  Bibliography is better in single spacing
               %            but you may choose different
               %            Don't use \singlespacing if your thesis
               %            is already in single spacing
%
\printbibliography

\doublespacing

% Appendices are optional.
%
% The standard `\appendix` macro will not put the word "appendix" before
% table of contents entries.
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/adding-the-word-appendix-to-table-of-contents-in-latex
\begin{appendices}  
\subfile{\main/tex/background.tex}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}




Welcome to TeX.SE.  Copy everything to a new project.  Start cutting material from the chapter files until you get the minimal amount so that chapter 3 still doesn't show up.  Cut material from your preamble until the same.  Then post the trimmed files here, along with that for chapter 2.  And make sure you're not getting any compilation errors along the way.

what is \left  before the list of tables???? we can not use your example as you have not posted anything that we can run, but surely that gives an error? \left is a math command for large brackets?

@DavidCarlisle, I have deleted the \left before the listoffigures but nothing has changed, the problem is i am getting the error
File `./tex/chapter_3.tex' not found. \subfile{\main/tex/chapter_3.tex}
but chapter_3 is obviously in the correct directory , There are a lot of figures so you may get a lot of errors if i send you something that can run.

check if chapter 2 changes the definition of \main.

`\providecommand{\main}{..}
\documentclass[\main/thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\onlyinsubfile{\zexternaldocument*{\main/tex/introduction}}
\usepackage{ mathtools, dblfloatfix}`
chapter_2 has the above starting

if you get any error ignore the generated pdf, and ask about the error message, tex makes no attempt to generate usable pdf after an error, it's just a debugging aid.

Naturally if tex can not find the file ``./tex/chapter_3.tex' not found.then the file contents will not appear, you should have put this information in the question, and you can remove everything in the example unrelated to that error. Personally I would simply use\include` and not subfiles which adds complication, but it should work.

but how come chapter_3 just runs and shows up in resulted pdf file when i put it before chapter_2 ?

I found out that the problem is due to my table of contents page are not long enough to fit the table of contents, that's why chapter_3 doesn't show up at all, after I change the name of the chapter_3 to chapter_4 it somewhat works, now the question is how can i fit all of these chapters with subsections to the table of contents.

you are not providing any information that would allow anyone to help, you have posted code that can not be run to see the issue and are not describing important information such as error messages.

I found the solution to my problem, When i was connecting the chapters together, i was using
%\onlyinsubfile{\zexternaldocument*{\main/tex/introduction}}

to connect one chapter to another but somewhat my long chapter namely chapter_2 was not appearing in the correct order, since this section and its subsections are quite long, my tableofcontents section was not displaying the remaining sections in order, to solve the problem I inserted the following line before the end of the document. And now i can link them easily.
\subfile{chapter3.tex} %Insert relative before file
